# AngularJS Break promise chain

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

How to break chain promises in AngularJS?

Here is plunk with comment in app.js, where I want to break chain.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MBBWJGwPfy2Wz13yczvV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use `defer.reject` method:

```
       var defer = $q.defer();

       /* .. */
       response.data.name = response.data.name + " error(2)";

        if(<drop me>){
           defer.reject( response );
            return defer.promise;
        }

        return response;
        /* .. */
```

By this way you will go to *error* callback

See <kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qa1MukHTUHgCnZQjzwwM?p=preview)</kbd>

> Remember, you can resolve/reject a promise only once!

Comment: Try to press Get Data button one or few times. It's working not correct.

Comment: Just move `var defer = $q.defer();` into the drop section. Changed Plunker

Answer (score 0):

in general you don't return the result(in your case response), you should return a promise instead. And then you resolve the promise with your result:

```
var deferred = q.defer();
deferred.resolve(response);
return deferred.promise;
```

or reject the promise

```
deferred.reject(response);
```

or give back an already rejected promise

```
return $q.reject(response)
```

Either if you reject or resolve the promise the success or error function will be called in the next then-statement.